# Выравнивание части списка li

Tags: php, html, css

**Здравствуйте, хотел бы узнать как сделать 4 элемента таблицы (li) по середине.**

Я использую только php, html, css!

Сам код:

```
<?php

  include 'config.php';

  function ShowElementsShop($shop){
    foreach ($shop as $key => $value) {
      list($name[$key], $description[$key], $img[$key], $price[$key]) = $shop[$key];
      echo "<li>";
      echo "<h3>$name[$key]</h3>";
      echo "<p>$description[$key]</p>";
      echo "<span>$price[$key]</span>";
    }
  }

  // echo ShowElementsShop($shop, 0, 1);
?>
<style media="screen">
  div {
    position: relative;
    background: #f3f3f3f3;
    width: 60%;

    left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  div > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative; left: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px;
    min-width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<div class="">
<?=ShowElementsShop($shop)?>
</div>
```

Конфиг:

```
$shop = [

  [
    'Test', //Name
    'Тут может быть описание', //description
    'fg/rfdg', //URL Img
    '200', //price
    [], //command
  ],

  [
    'Test', //Name
    'Тут может быть описание', //description
    'fg/rfdg', //URL Img
    '200', //price
    [], //command
  ],

];
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще Вам ненужно проводить никаких манипуляций с родительским элементом(ширина и transform). Так как li у Вас отображается как "inline-block", то достаточно родительскому блоку указать text-align center. Обратите внимание что li находится не в ul а это невалидная верстка.

Comment: Спасибо. Большое спасибо

Comment: Но, что-то не ровно. Вот скрин - http://prntscr.com/igr801

Comment: Ну вообще то они по центру.Если вы имеете введу что последний элемент перескочил на вторую строчку, то это решается таким способом. Родителю - font-size:0; дочерним элемента font-size:16px; и занулением внешних отступов.Но опять же  у Вас ширина стоит 20% сумма ширины всех элементов 100% они просто займут всю ширину родителя.

Comment: Отступы неровные http://prntscr.com/igrav2

Comment: Полагаю проблема в этом правиле position: relative; left: 1%;

Comment: Я его удалил. http://prntscr.com/igrd50

Comment: как я уже говорил ранее уберите все манипуляции с позиционированием родительского блока http://prntscr.com/igrez3

Comment: http://prntscr.com/igrg6t | http://mrskoper.ru/ | Посмотрите. 1 Это скрин     2 Сайт

Comment: http://prntscr.com/igrip7.